# Notation clarification needed for an exercise from Arbib and Manes text.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, equivalence-relations

The following question, is taken from Arbib and Manes’ *Arrows, structures and functors* text:

> **Definition 1:**  Given an equivalence relation $E$ on a set $A$, we define the **equivalence class** of an element $a$ of $A$ with respect to $E$ to be
> $$
>   [a]_E = \{a' \mid \text{$a'\in A$ and $(a,a')\in E$}\}
> $$
> (when no ambiguity can arise, we write $[a]$ for $[a]_E$.) The **factor set** or **quotient set of $A$ with respect to $E$** is then the set of equivalence classes
> $$
>   A/E = \{[a] \mid a \in A\} \,.
> $$
>
> **Definition 2:** Given any function $f \colon A \rightarrow B$, we define the **equivalence relation $E(f)$ of $f$** on $A$ by
> $$
>   E(f) = \{ (a,a') \in A \times A \mid f(a) = f(a') \}.
> $$
>
> […]
>
> Given *any* relation $R$ on $A$ (i.e., any subset of $A \times A$) we may associate with it the two projection maps
> $$
>   p_k \colon R \rightarrow A \,, \quad (a_1, a_2) \mapsto a_k \,, \quad k = 1, 2 \,.
> $$
> On the other hand, given any pair of maps
> $$
>   p_1, p_2 \colon R \rightarrow A
> $$
> with common domain, and with codomain $A$, we may define on $A$ the corresponding relation
> $$
>   E_R = \{ (p_1(r), p_2(r)) \mid r \in R\} \subset A \times A
>   \tag{$1$}
> $$
> (where we forbear writing $E_{(R, p_1, p_2)}$ for brevity).

> **Exercise:** Given relations $p_1, p_2 \colon R \rightarrow A$, $q_1, q_2 \colon S \rightarrow A$, say that $(p_1, p_2) \sim (q_1, q_2)$ if there exist functions (not necessarily isomorphisms!) as shown below:
>
> [image]
>
> Show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.  Show that $[R,p,q] \mapsto E_R$ is a well defined bijection from the set of $\sim$-equivalence classes of relations to the set of subsets of $A \times A$.

> Let $x_1$ be the map that sends $R$ to $S$ and $x_2$ be the map that sends $S$ to $R$. From the above commutative diagram, we also define another exact lookin diagrams but with one pair of mappings renamed to $z_1$ and $z_2$ along with defining the following mapping/identities:
>
> - $p_1=q_1\circ x_1, \quad (1)$
> - $p_2=q_2\circ x_1$,
> - $q_1=p_1\circ x_2, \quad (2)$
> - $q_2=p_2\circ x_2,$
> - $q_1=z_1\circ x_3, \quad (3)$
> - $q_2=z_2\circ x_3,$
> - $z_1=q_1\circ x_4, \quad (4)$
> - $z_2=q_2\circ x_4.$
>
> To show that $\sim$ is reflexive, applying $(1)$ to itself twice, we get $p_1 = p_1 \circ x_1 \circ x_2$ and $p_2 = p_2 \circ x_1 \circ x_2$, hence $(p_1, p_2) \sim (p_1, p_2)$.
>
> For symmetry, from $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have $(p_1, p_2) \sim (q_1, q_2)$ and $(q_1, q_2) \sim (p_1, p_2)$, so we get symmetry.
>
> For transitivity from $(1)$ and $(3)$, $(p_1, p_2) \sim (q_1, q_2)$, and $(q_1, q_2) \sim (z_1, z_2)$. Then plugging $(3)$ into $(1)$, we get $p_1 = z_1 \circ x_3 \circ x_1$ and $p_2 = z_2 \circ x_3 \circ x_1$, hence $(p_1, p_2) \sim (z_1, z_2)$.

For showing that the function $[R, p, q] \mapsto E_R$ is well-defined and bijective, **can someone tell me what the notations $[R, p, q]$ means?** I know there is a misprint there. The notations should read as $[R_i, p_j, p_j]$ and $E_{R_i}$ for $i, j = 1, 2$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think there's a typo here - it just means any that the equivalence class (under $\sim$) of the triple $R, p, q$ (where $p,q: R\to A$) is sent to the subset $E_{R,p,q}$ of $A\times A$

Comment: @Matthew Towers does it mean something like $f_{R_i}(p, q)=(p(r), q(r))$?  I am not certain as to what is the input for ${R,p,q]$ and output for $E_R$?

Comment: your comment doesn't make much sense to me - what are $R_i$ or $f_{R_i}$ or $r$?  The input to the map they are describing is the equivalence class of the triple $R, p, q$ and the output is the subset $E_{(R, p, q)}$ of $A\times A$, that's what the notation $[R, p, q]\mapsto E_R$ means.

Comment: @MatthewTowers sorry i am still confused.  For any elements in $E_R$, does it take the form $(p(r),q(r))$, where $r\in R$?  I am not clear what is the domain and codomain of the stated function, also, the notation feels horrible.  Am I suppose to plug in three elements into the function, $R$, $p$, and $q$.  Usually when a function say $f$ is given, it usually is presented as $f$ maps to $X$ and $Y$ such that $f(x)=y$.....

Comment: It would be my guess that $[R,p,q]$ is an unfortunate choice of letters for the clearer $[R,p_1,p_2]$. The tuple $(R,p_1,p_2)$ should just encode a set $R$ and two functions $p_{1,2}:R\to A$. With square brackets, it should denote an equivalence class under $\sim$, so, if $R,S,p_{1,2},q_{1,2}$ are as in the diagram, we would say $[R,p_1,p_2]=[S,q_1,q_2]$. To say the assignment to $E_{(R,p_{1,2})}$ is well-defined is to say it does not matter whether we used $(R,p_1,p_2)$ or $(S,q_1,q_2)$ as a representative of the $\sim$ class.

Comment: @FShrike so to show that $E_{(R, p_{1,2})}=E_{(S, q_{1,2})}$, I first show $(q_1(r), q_2(r))\in  E_{(S, q_{1,2})}\subset E_{(R, p_{1,2})}$ and similarly $(p_1(r), p_2(r))\in  E_{(R, p_{1,2})}\subset E_{(S, q_{1,2})}$?

Comment: Pretty much, this is the usual way. Caveat: I haven’t done it myself so there’s a risk my interpretation is wrong

Comment: @FShrike ah kk. Thank you so much for looking over my question.